# Access other person's forked repo

Tags: git, github

The problem: I have already cloned a repository from github, let us call it `git_repo`. Thus, `git_repo` exists as a directory on my Desktop.
A co-worker of mine has forked `git_repo`. Their fork contains code which does not exist locally on my machine. Their code only exists on the fork and not on `main`.
I am now taking over my co-workers project so I need to access the code they have been working on.
My question is how should I do this.
I cannot have two directories on my Desktop both of name `git_repo`.
I have tried to do:

```
$ git remote add theirusername git@github.com:theirusername/reponame.git
$ git fetch theirusername
$ git checkout -b mynamefortheirbranch theirusername/theirbranch
```

however, this has not worked for me.
Specifically, running `git remote add theirusername git@github.com:theirusername/reponame.git` returns `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`
Should I ask my co-worker to merge their fork with the `main` branch? However, their fork contains multiple merge conflicts.
I am unsure on what the proper git hygiene is in this case.
Is it possible to transfer owernership of a forked repo? More explicitly I mean that the forks as listed on github change from: `their_username/git_repo` to `my_username/git_repo`.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: That error indicates that you were not executing that command from within a Git repo.

Comment: I executed the command within the Git repo and now the error is: `error: remote their_user already exists.`

Comment: Try `git remote -v` to see what remotes you have configured so far. That message tells me you've already successfully added a remote called `their_user`, but `git remote -v` will confirm that.

Comment: By the way, yes, you can certainly have two local sandboxes pointing to the original and the fork: just rename one of them. Or use `git clone <url-to-their-fork> reponame-fork`. The directory name of your sandbox does not have to be related to the remote's name, it's just a convenient default to make it the same. But adding a second remote is probably the better way to go for you anyway, so you were already on the right track.

Comment: thank you joanis. your comment resolved by question. I will now comment the answer for others and give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

@joanis's comment was able to help me. They said to just type
`git clone <url-to-their-fork> reponame-fork`.
A more in depth explanation is in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `git remote` command inside your local repository, then the rest of the commands should work.

However, this is the first step, you are going to need to learn how to integrate his remote branch, so it would help you to read the relevant chapter in the ProGit book: [Git Branching - Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches). For setting up the remote in the first place: [Git Basics - Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).